# rubygems/dependency.rb:311:in `to_specs': Could not find 'jekyll-theme-cayman' (Gem::MissingSpecError)

Tags: rubygems, jekyll, github-pages

I just started trying to use Github.io so I apologize profusely for my ignorance and I have spent 6 hours trying to find an answer.

I tried to rebuild my pages after making a change by adding front matter to index.md, to display on a local server and received the following error:
Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:311:in `to_specs': Could not find 'jekyll-theme-cayman' (>= 0) among 88 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError) Checked in 'GEM_PATH=C:/Users/Jane/.gem/ruby/2.7.0;C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0', execute` gem env` for more information.

I had already pushed the change to github, and now the theme is wiped out on that environment as well.

I tried adding back the theme on Github settings and it made no difference. I tried manually editing _config.yml on Github committing to a new branch, making a pull request and then merging the request trying to get Jekyll to engage and this also produced no results.

This happened the last time I tried to make a change (yesterday) and I had to delete the repository and start over. So far, it seems that there is a missing set of instructions on how to use themes and I am thinking at this point I'd be better off ditching Jekyll and writing my own site completely from scratch, but I'm so determined to solve this I want to know. Any help appreciated.